# Count nan in data string with python

Tags: python, string, numpy, count, nan

I am trying to count 'nan' in my data file.

For this purpose, I have used two codes
one is:

```
with  open(filin,'r') as f:
    arrays = [map(float, line.split(',')) for line in f]
newa = [x[6] for x in arrays]
```

The other is:

```
for columns in ( raw.strip().split(',') for raw in f ):
      a.append((columns[6])
newa = np.array(a)
```

When I used the first way, I got error message of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Count_nan.py", line 13, in <module>
arrays = [map(float, line.split(',')) for line in f]
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

With second code, I can get arrays, but I could not count nan with the code of

```
l = np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(newa)) or


v = [len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(newa, key=np.isnan) if key]
```

v is code for counting group of consecutive 'nan's.

The reason which I can't use two code above is that my newa is consist of `['1', '2.4','nan'...]`, not `[1, 2.4, nan, ...]`

Any idea or help would be really appreciated.

Beat regards,

Isaac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using `numpy`, it makes a lot of sense to use `genfromtxt` to read data, instead of doing it manually, and then it should just work:

```
In [43]:

%%file temp.txt
1,2.4,nan
1,2.4,nan
Overwriting temp.txt
In [44]:

arr=np.genfromtxt('temp.txt',delimiter=',')
arr
Out[44]:
array([[ 1. ,  2.4,  nan],
       [ 1. ,  2.4,  nan]])
In [45]:

np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(arr))
Out[45]:
2
```

Also, if you are only reading the 7th column from you data file, supply `usecols=[6]` to `genfromtxt`.

To find the longest run of `nan` is easy:

```
In [57]:

import itertools
In [58]:

arr
Out[58]:
array([ 1. ,  2.4,  nan,  1. ,  2.4,  nan,  nan,  nan])
In [59]:

max([len(list(v)) for i, v in itertools.groupby(np.isnan(arr)) if i])
Out[59]:
3
```

Comment: Thank you CT Zhu, Do you mean "arr=np.genfromtxt('temp.txt, delimiter=',',usecols=[6])?

Comment: Yep, also, to get the longest run of `nan`s is easy with using `itertools.groupby`, see edit.

Comment: Thank you CT Zhu, However problem of my data is ['1','2','nan',..], not [1,2,nan,...]. I will try now, but do you think that your idea would work for this case as well?

Comment: `genfromtxt` will read data into `float` in this case, and I was thinking `[1,2,nan,...]` is the desired result, right?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe change this

```
newa = np.array(a)
```

to this:

```
newa = np.array(a).astype(float)
```

or just:

```
newa = newa.astype(float)
```

Answer (score 1):

how bout just

```
open(filin,'r').read().count("nan")
```

if you really just want to count "nan" at least

(as an aside `float("nan")` works fine ... so you are obviously passing in something else that cannot be converted to a float)

Comment: Thank you Joran, your idea is great. Also, I would like to try to count consecutive "nan". My purpose is to find the largest consecutive "nan" in the list. I usually used "v = [len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(newa, key=np.isnan) if key]" and print max(v). However, I couldn't apply this code for this case. Thank you, Isaac